Oracle bitmap_construct_agg matview with fast refresh
The question is:
Is that possible?
Or, because of bitmap_construct_agg returns BLOB or RAW it is not possible at all?
This is my test case:
create table testmvb(id number, subid number);
 create  materialized view log on testmvb with sequence, rowid(id, subid) including new values;
  
   create materialized view testmvb_mv 
   refresh fast on commit 
   as 
   select id, 
    bitmap_construct_agg(subid) subids,
    bitmap_bucket_number(subid) buk,
    count(*) cnt_all
   from testmvb 
   group by id, bitmap_bucket_number(subid);

Only refresh full  refreshes column subids...
TIA,
Andrew.

Tested here on a 21c and the MV is refreshed. Did you forgot to commit before checking if new values are in ?

Are you sure that column subids from my example refreshes after fast refresh? I cannot achieve  such a result

This from 19.22
SQL> create table testmvb(id number, subid number);

Table created.

SQL>  create  materialized view log on testmvb with sequence, rowid(id, subid) including new values;

Materialized view log created.

SQL>
SQL>    create materialized view testmvb_mv
  2     refresh fast on commit
  3     as
  4     select id,
  5      bitmap_construct_agg(subid) subids,
  6      bitmap_bucket_number(subid) buk,
  7      count(*) cnt_all
  8     from testmvb
  9     group by id, bitmap_bucket_number(subid);

Materialized view created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into    testmvb values (1,10);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into    testmvb values (2,20);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into    testmvb values (3,30);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL>
SQL> select * from testmvb_mv;

        ID SUBIDS                                BUK    CNT_ALL
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         1 000004                                  1          1
         2 00000010                                1          1
         3 0000000040                              1          1

So I'm seeing what I would expect. Can you elucidate more on exactly what you are seeing?

Looks like a misunderstanding of bitmap_construct_agg(): some insert with existing ID may indeed not modify the subids, but the MV refresh works: the CNT_ALL is updated, as both tests on 21 and 19 show up.

Just try after all these steps: insert into    testmvb values (1,11); commit; cnt_all will be updated, but not subids.

Only refresh complete works for me...
